# nose get list of test without running them

Tags: python, testing, nose

Is there a way to get a list of all the tests currently recognized by nose, without running them?

According to the doc 
`--collect-only Enable collect-only:  Collect and output test names only, don't run any tests.  [COLLECT_ONLY]`

However when I do `nosetests --collect-only` I get:

```
Ran 101 tests in 0.642s

OK
```

How can I get names those tests?

Answer (score 1):

Try with the `-v` option:

```
nosetests -v --collect-only
```

If you're trying to debug how nose actually finds your tests, go for `-vv`